# Java-How Do I Rerefrence Sqlite Database in the Same Folder With My Project Files?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

am working on a certain java Management System where am using sqlite as my primary database. Am using netbeans gui builder to work on my project. I have googled and stack overflowed how to reference sqlite database in the same dir with my project files without including full path like `c://filepath` but nothing promising yet. I don't want to include the full path to my database, I want to use sqlite file from the project files so that everything will work smoothly even after distributing my project...

My Connection Class currently Looks like this;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Connect {
    private static Connection con = null; 

    public static Connection connecting(){

        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:programming.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Working", null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
        }
        return con; 
    }

}
```

However that's seems not to work.. Remember Connection class and database are saved in the same dir...

Please note am avoiding absolute path like `c://users/programming.sqlite`

Anything to help please???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it must work as you shown, but, you can load `programming.sqlite` as a `java.io.File` and then put absolute path into jdbc url connection. I mean this:

```
File temp = new File("programming.sqlite");
String connection = "jdbc:sqlite:" + temp.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\","\\\\");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
...
```

If this code doesn't work for you, then your problem must be with `programming.sqlite` location, because in this case it is not on the same home dir of your java programm.

Comment: Nice one to test your answer i have created a table called testing.. and all I can get is `java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: testing)`

Comment: When I include the absolute path like `C:\\file_path` the database works well but i don't want to use this approach

Comment: Oh! sorry, of course you have to escape filePath, that is wy my first answer didn't work for you. I edited my answer to add this `temp.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\","\\\\")` this way it works.

Comment: Not working yet... Would you please try it and see if it's going to work... Am not sure where am going wrong...

Comment: I can't check it, I am GNU/Linux developer and can't test on windows path. But maybe you issue is related with file loading. You can check it with `exists` method on file. After loading file, try to check if it exist this way `temp.exists()`. A false value means you don't reach the file, so this is the bug to solve.